# Buying Colab credits for new-grads

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm doing a session on generative AI art for a few new-grads in the company. I'd love for them to have compute units to play around with, and I'm willing to pay for them but I don't think there's a feature which allows me to buy credits for others.

Is there a way for me to buy credits for others?